# Performance issue with "select" SQLite requests

Tags: wpf, sqlite, ado.net

I am working on a personnal WPF project where I parse large texts, extract paragraphs, sentences and words. For each word I parse, I send a "select" request into a 480k row/10 columns database that I converted in SQLite for the ease of deployment.

My problem is that each of those requests are adding a huge delay on the global processing time (I spend 1,02 sec/word average instead of 30ms without the select request). I have a few ideas to solve this, and I wanted your opinion on it before I investgate further an option:

- I could fill a datatable with my 480k rows table. I expect it to increase both the speed and the RAM used (in the current setup I use around 40Mo max). As I have no experience with datasets/datatables, I'm not sure if it's a good idea regarding both speed and RAM consumption. Would it be too much?
- I could insert my words into a separate SQLite table in the same database and use a SQlite feature to join databases. No experience in this either, I wonder if it is possible to create a view composed of columns from both tables, one of them (common to both) being used for matching. I could work on the resulting database, whether it is a simple view or a real table

  One last question: I managed to reduce drastically the processing time by using a single transaction for my batch of inserts SQLite. I assume it is not possible with "SELECT" requests. However, I would welcome a surprise technique to achieve that :-)

Comment: A question, why do you need to do select? do you want to display it? can you improve the performance with lazy loading with mix of data virtualization?

Comment: The parsing task is meant to create a record of each word associated with several properties that I get from my 480k rows table. For now, this record is kept as a list of structures where I merge the original data and the data obtained with the select request. Once this record is complete, I will use it to create and display charts and figures to summarize it. To answer your question, I do not display it directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this myself in a satisfying way (to me at least). I used the datatable option. The RAM consumption has jumped to 230Mo but I consider that it can be tolerated in the context of an heavy string analysis.

As expected, it is around 900x faster.